# Eevee crash upon adding extra light

Tags: eevee-render-engine

My scene is very low poly (1120 faces), has just one point light, camera resolution is 1080x1920, yet when I add 2 extra lights in Eevee it crashes. This has happened with various scenes and this is not the first time it is happening. Also, no subsurf is used or any modifier and no textures or anything fancy. Just a plain lowpolyesque scene. Please help how do I fix it.

PS: This doesn't happen in Cycles.

Answer (score 1):

After too much tinkering with eevee setting i finally found the solution. Shadows. Yes, i disabled the high bit depth in shadows and reduced cube size from 4096 to 512.

This reduction did not affect the quality of my scene as i said it was very low poly. But this would definitely affect high quality eevee scenes.